# "answer" e "response" são ambos traduzidos para "resposta"

Tags: debate, bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Na página de usuário em sites em inglês temos isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na versão em português, ficou isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que em português ficaram duas abas com o mesmo título "respostas". A primeira aba "respostas" refere-se à respostas a perguntas. A segunda refere-se a réplicas, tréplicas e discussões recebidas. Acho que a primeira aba "respostas" deveria manter o nome e a segunda deveria mudar. A questão é, mudar para o que?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Talvez a tradução de *responses* poderia ser réplicas.

Comment: Eu adicionei outra opção que me parece mais transparente face ao conteúdo "dentro" do separador. Não leves a mal dizer isto mas no meu entender "réplicas" não é uma palavra capaz de descrever o conteúdo que vais visualizar. Fica sempre a pergunta "Réplicas do que?" Bom, por outro lado a agora que penso nisso a pergunta é capaz de puxar pela curiosidade de cada um e levar a um clique para visitar o separador ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Quando acedi ao segundo separador "respostas" e visualizei o tipo de conteúdo, o que me veio à cabeça foi "Isto é o feedback do sistema para o meu utilizador".

## Feedback

> feedback |fidebéque|
>   (palavra inglesa)
>   substantivo masculino
>
> 1. Retroacção das correcções e regulações de um sistema de informações sobre o centro de comando do sistema; acção exercida sobre as causas de um fenómeno pelo próprio fenómeno.
> 2. Reacção a alguma coisa. = RESPOSTA, RETORNO
>      Nota: Também se escreve com hífen: feed-back.
>
> "feedback", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/feedback [consultado em 26-12-2013].

---

Claro que pode não ser bem aceite por todos um site em Português com uma estrangeirismo, onde nesse caso sugeria:

### Retorno

Comment: Podia ser assim no SO principal também, porque lá fica a mesma pergunta: "responses" a quê?